# I'm using a very simple slider. How to stop the loop when the user clicks

Tags: jquery, loops, slider, settimeout, eventtrigger

I'm using a slider called squareslider.

FInd the code attached

```
    (function($){

    $('.square-slider').each(function(){
        var slider = $(this),
            slides = slider.find('.slide'),
            currentSlide = 0;

        slides.show();
        $(slides[currentSlide]).addClass('active');
        $('.next,.prev', slider).show();

        $('.prev', slider).on('click', function(){
            slides.removeClass('active');
            currentSlide--;
            if(currentSlide < 0) currentSlide = slides.length - 1;
            $(slides[currentSlide]).addClass('active');
            return false;
        });

        $('.next', slider).on('click', function(){
            slides.removeClass('active');
            currentSlide++;
            if(currentSlide > slides.length - 1) currentSlide = 0;
            $(slides[currentSlide]).addClass('active');
            return false;
        });
    });


swapC()

function swapC() {
    $('.next').trigger("click");
    window.setTimeout(function() { swapC() }, 6000)
}

})(window.jQuery);
```

as you can see the slider was manual (it would slide just on click on the div with classes .prev and .next) so I use the setTimeout to simulate a click that makes the slide "flip" every 6 seconds.

When the user actually clicks on one of the arrows of the slider I would like the slider to stop but because it is not possible to distinguish the "triggered" click from the real one I'm a bit stuck.

Do you guys have any idea on how to accomplish this? Maybe finding a way to activate the slider without simulating the click in the loop?

Thanks a lot guys

Any Idea?

Comment: just clear the timeout by keeping reference uid on it and calling `clearTimeout(uid);`

Answer (score 0):

Clear the timeout by keeping reference uid on it and calling `clearTimeout()` function:

```
(function ($) {
    var timeout;
    $('.square-slider').each(function () {
        var slider = $(this),
            slides = slider.find('.slide'),
            currentSlide = 0;

        slides.show();
        $(slides[currentSlide]).addClass('active');
        $('.next,.prev', slider).show();

        $('.prev', slider).on('click', function () {
            slides.removeClass('active');
            currentSlide--;
            if (currentSlide < 0) currentSlide = slides.length - 1;
            $(slides[currentSlide]).addClass('active');
            return false;
        });

        $('.next', slider).on('click', function () {
            slides.removeClass('active');
            currentSlide++;
            if (currentSlide > slides.length - 1) currentSlide = 0;
            $(slides[currentSlide]).addClass('active');
            return false;
        });

        $('.stop', slider).on('click', function () {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            return false;
        });
    });


    swapC()

    function swapC() {
        $('.next').trigger("click");
        timeout = window.setTimeout(swapC, 6000)
    }

})(window.jQuery);
```